# pandas multi-index select data by logical arrays

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, conditional-statements, multi-index

here i has a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100).reshape(20,5), columns=list('abcde'))
data = data.set_index(['a', 'b'])
print(data.head())
        c   d   e
a  b
0  1    2   3   4
5  6    7   8   9
10 11  12  13  14
15 16  17  18  19
20 21  22  23  24
```

How can i select data use loc functions by the logical judge?
Like this:  a<20 and b > 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = (data.index.get_level_values('a') < 20) & (data.index.get_level_values('b') > 1)
print (mask)
[False  True  True  True False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False]

print (data[mask])
        c   d   e
a  b             
5  6    7   8   9
10 11  12  13  14
15 16  17  18  19
```

Solution with [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) is similar as another answer, only changed `&` to `and`:

```
print (data.query("a < 20 and b > 1"))
        c   d   e
a  b             
5  6    7   8   9
10 11  12  13  14
15 16  17  18  19
```

[Query python versus pandas syntax comparison](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#query-python-versus-pandas-syntax-comparison).

Answer (score 2):

1) Use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) directly on names of indices of the multi-indexed `DF` to perform boolean indexing:

```
data.query("a < 20 & b > 1")
```

2) Use [`eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html) if you want to have a boolean mask beforehand and subset the `DF` based on this later:

```
bool_mask = data.eval("a < 20 & b > 1")
data[bool_mask]
```

Resulting o/p for both cases:

[image]